# Display video field at front side

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom type show, which have a video clip attached to it.

I displayed all fields on my theme but i have difficulties about displaying the video clip.

In my backoffice, you add a media file(the video clip) on my show.

I tried some wordpress functions but i din't find a solution.

Thanks for your reading,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code may help you :

```
<?php 
    $sc_video_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'meta_key',true); //place or meta key into it too get saved video file url
?>
<div class="responsive-video">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="<?php echo esc_url($sc_video_url);  ?>" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="<?php echo esc_url($sc_video_url);  ?>" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```